# How do I access the state from a child component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, state

I'm trying to use React Redux with React Native and I'm struggling to get it working properly.

Check out this Expo Snack for a demo: https://snack.expo.io/@southdevondigital/sadistic-candies

As you can see it's just a basic app with 3 screens and some inline navigation buttons. I've set up my redux store and reducer, but when I try and access the state from within a component, I get a `Cannot read property 'getState' of undefined` error (see the Settings screen in the Snack for an example).

Comment: Look into how to use react-redux's `connect` function in conjunction with `mapStateToProps`

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to `connect()` is to use [hooks](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks).

If you have a store with the structure:

```
{
  settings: {
    optionValue: 234
  }
}
```

Then you can access it in your code like so:

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const MyComponent = () => {
  const optionValue = useSelector(state => state.settings.optionValue);

  return (
    <p>{optionValue}</p>
  );

}

export default MyComponent;
```

Similarly, you can use the `useDispatch` hook to update the state:

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";

const MyComponent = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const optionValue = useSelector(state => state.settings.optionValue);

  const handleClick = () => {
    const newValue = 123;
    dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_VALUE', value: newValue });
  }

  return (
    <p>{optionValue}</p>
    <button onClick={handleClick} />
  );

}

export default MyComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally if you want to get access to the redux store in a React component, you'll have to "connect" it to the store and map in the state props you want:

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const MyComponent = props => {
  return <p>{props.somethingFromState}</p>;
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  somethingFromState: state.something
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent);
```

At this point, the default export from the file will be a component connected to your redux store that has access to `state.something`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `connect` to connect a component to state with `mapStateToProps`.

Redux state that you 'map-to-props' will be available via your connected components props

To update redux state use action creators that are also passed to component props via the second arg to `connect`

You can now convert `Settings` to a functional component:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default Settings = (props) => {
    const { value } = props;

    return (
      <View>
        <Text>
          This is the settings screen. I want to render a value from the state here: { value }
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
}
const mapStateToProps(state){
  return {
    value: state.value
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Settings)
```

You'll need a reducer:

```
export default const reducer = (state = '', action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'UPDATE_VALUE' :
            return action.payload
        case 'REMOVE_VALUE' :
            return ''
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

You will also need some action creators as well:

```
export const updateValue = (newValue) = {
    return {type: 'UPDATE_VALUE', payload:newValue}
}
export const removeValue = (newValue) = {
    return {type: 'REMOVE_VALUE'}
}
```

You can then use these action creators to update state:

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Button } from 'react-native-paper';
import { updateValue , removeValue } from './actions'

const SomeComponent = props => {
  return(
        <div>
            <Button onPress={()=>props.updateValue(‘newValue’)}>Update</button>
            <Button onPress={()=>props.removeValue()}>Remove</button>
        </div>
  )
}

//set mapStateToProps arg to null if you do not need state
export default connect(null , {updateValue , removeValue})(SomeComponent);
```